# Horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel and button in a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

Thank you for who paying attention and read my question.

I am a new to Angular and Typescript language.
Currently I am able to scroll the division using button control, and I wish to scroll the division using mouse wheel too.

I have try some code, as example:

```
<div ... (wheel)="onWheel($event)" ... ><div>

onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
   (<Element>event.target).parentElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

But it seem not working on my project.

And Here is my HTML code:

```
<button mat-button class="prevBut" (click)="scrollLeft()"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon </button>

<div #widgetsContent class="widgetDiv" (wheel)="onWheel($event)">
</div>

<button mat-button class="prevBut" (click)="scrollRight()"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>
```

Here is my Typescript code:

```
 public scrollRight(): void {
        this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 150), behavior: 'smooth' });  
 }

 public scrollLeft(): void {
        this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 150), behavior: 'smooth' });
 }

 onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
       (event.target as Element).parentElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
       event.preventDefault();
 }
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestion, of how would the best way be to proceed further.

Comment: Why aren't you using css `max-width` and `overflow-x: scroll` to achieve what you want?

Comment: This is my CSS code.
```
.widgetDiv{
                    display: flex;
                    overflow: auto;
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                    width: -moz-available;      
                    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for anyone who paying attention to my problems. I have solved this by myself luckily. This is the answer how i solve it.

```
onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
       this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
       event.preventDefault();
 }
```